# How to create event listener when message from firebase received in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, event-listener, eventhandler

I am using firebase to receive messages. When message received (onMessageReceived()). I want to check whether the message contains required string (say "hello"). If yes, i want it to be known to another fragment, so that some method in fragment will be called based on message.

For this i want to create event listener when message received.
In my fragment, two APIs will be called. on API will be called onCreatedView().
based on message from firebase , second API should be called.
The two API calls should be done within fraction of milliseconds.

MyFireBaseMessage.java

```
public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("message here","message here "+ remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    String value = remoteMessage.getData().get("msg");
    Log.d("value here","value here"+" "+value);
    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("hello"))
    {
        //implement custom event listener here
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where you've implemented FirebaseListener.. post your code. it's difficult to help without knowing how you've coded the stuff. please post relevant code only.

Comment: @SahilManchanda - i've edited my question and posted firebase message class. Hope you will understand. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Please check my answer, it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I can think of right now is using LocalBroadcast. to do this

1. Amend your Firebase service and put this content

   ```
   public class MyMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
   private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
   }


   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
       Log.d("message here", "message here " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
       String value = remoteMessage.getData().get("msg");
       Log.d("value here", "value here" + " " + value);
       if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("hello")) {
           Intent intent = new Intent("custom-listener");
           broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent)
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Make changes in your fragment class

public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

```
    Context context;
    BroadcastReceiver br;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }

    private void setup() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("custom-listener"));
    }


    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
        }
    };

}
```

with broadcasts you will be able to listen to the event you want to. The onReceive method inside the Fragment class will get fired when your if condition is true i.e. `value.equalsIgnoreCase("hello")`

Apologies for the formatting of this answer. having difficulties adjusting it.

Comment: Sahil Manchanda - it seems method send() is never used. Also , what is "custom-event-name" in send().

Comment: @Eswar i used send method to test the broadcast. it's not required.  and "custom-event-name" should've been custom-listener

Comment: Sahil Manchanda - Thank you so much for your help. It worked as expected. Also i was busy in making some changes. Apologies for delay in replying.

Comment: @Eswar np, glad it worked. Please accept and upvote the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, if **hello** is key in message format

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("hello")) {
}
```

Or if **hello** is as message string, then try this

```
Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
JSONObject fullObject = new JSONObject(params);
String messageString = fullObject.getString("msg");
```

Hope it works!!

Answer (score 0):

For this use the Local broadcast receiver in your app

example:

in notification screen use the receiver like this
@Override

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 

{
super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
Log.d("message here", "message here " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
String value = remoteMessage.getData().get("msg");
Log.d("value here", "value here" + " " + value);
if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("hello")) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("custom-listener");
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent)
}
}
and in fragment register broadcast receiver in onResume method  like this

 getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("custom-listener"));
```

also unregister the receiver in onPause nethod

```
       getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

and create broadcast  receiver method in  fragment where you can call the api , like this

```
 private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 


};
```